# php & PDO to filter sql table using couple selection boxes

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to filter data using drop-down related boxes.
Query works only with the first one.

I need help to make it work if:
-none selected, I want the query to load and display all data,
-only one or all or combination selected then as above

Here's my code so far:

```
<?php
include '../DBconnect.php';


$whereDept = $_POST["DeptNo"];
$whereArea = $_POST['AreaNo'];
$whereShift = $_POST['ShiftNo'];

$sql="SELECT 
MAX(myCount.7)'Jul',
MAX(myCount.8)'Aug',
MAX(myCount.9)'Sep',
MAX(myCount.10)'Oct',
MAX(myCount.11)'Nov',
MAX(myCount.12)'Dec',
MAX(myCount.1)'Jan',
MAX(myCount.2)'Feb',
MAX(myCount.3)'Mar',
MAX(myCount.4)'Apr',
MAX(myCount.5)'May',
MAX(myCount.6)'Jun'
FROM (SELECT 
COUNT(IF(month(dDateFound) = 7,1, NULL)) '7',
COUNT(IF(month(dDateFound) = 8,1, NULL)) '8',
COUNT(IF(month(dDateFound) = 9,1, NULL)) '9',
COUNT(IF(month(dDateFound) = 10,1, NULL)) '10',
COUNT(IF(month(dDateFound) = 11,1, NULL)) '11',
COUNT(IF(month(dDateFound) = 12,1, NULL)) '12',
COUNT(IF(month(dDateFound) = 1,1, NULL)) '1',
COUNT(IF(month(dDateFound) = 2,1, NULL)) '2',
COUNT(IF(month(dDateFound) = 3,1, NULL)) '3',
COUNT(IF(month(dDateFound) = 4,1, NULL)) '4',
COUNT(IF(month(dDateFound) = 5,1, NULL)) '5',
COUNT(IF(month(dDateFound) = 6,1, NULL)) '6'
FROM T_Defects INNER JOIN T_settings
WHERE (dDateFound >= `FYDateFROM` AND dDateFound <= `FYDateTO`) AND    (dDeptFK=:dDeptFK OR dAreaFK=:dAreaFK OR dShiftFK=:dShiftFK)
GROUP BY month(dDateFound))myCount";

$results = '';
try{  
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array('dDeptFK' => $whereDept, 'dAreaFK' => $whereArea, 'dShiftFK' => $whereShift));
$results = '<tr><th></th><th>Jul</th><th>Aug</th><th>Sep</th><th>Oct</th><th>Nov</th><th>Dec</th><th>Jan</th><th>Feb</th><th>Mar</th><th>Apr</th><th>May</th><th>Jun</th></tr>';
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) { 
$results .= '
           <tr> <td> Found           </td>
                <td>'. $row['Jul'] .'</td>
                <td>'. $row['Aug'] .'</td>
                <td>'. $row['Sep'] .'</td>
                <td>'. $row['Oct'] .'</td>
                <td>'. $row['Nov'] .'</td>
                <td>'. $row['Dec'] .'</td>
                <td>'. $row['Jan'] .'</td>
                <td>'. $row['Feb'] .'</td>
                <td>'. $row['Mar'] .'</td>
                <td>'. $row['Apr'] .'</td>
                <td>'. $row['May'] .'</td>
                <td>'. $row['Jun'] .'</td>
           </tr>
      ';
 }
 echo $results;

} catch(PDOException $e){
 echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();

}
?>
```

And this is the index.php page:

```
<?php
// include database connection
include '../DBconnect.php';
?>
<html>
<head>

     <!--  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">   </script>  -->
           <script src="jquery.js"></script> 

</head>
<body>



<p>
<h4>Current Fiscal Data:</h4>
<label>Department:</label>
    <div>
            <select name="dept" id="deptList" onchange="getId(this.value);">
                <option value="">-- Select Department --</option>
                <?php
           foreach($con->query('SELECT deptPK, deptName FROM T_Department') as $row) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['deptPK']; ?>"><?php echo $row["deptName"]; ?></option>
                <?php
        }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
            <label>Area:</label>
    <div>
            <select name="area" id="areaList" onchange="getId(this.value);">
                <option value="">-- Select Area --</option>
            </select>
        </div> 
    <label>Shift:</label>
    <div>
            <select name="shift" id="shiftList" >
                <option value="">-- Select Shift --</option>
            </select>
        </div> 
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#deptList').change(function(){  
       var deptPK = $(this).val();  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"getdataDefectsFound.php",  
            method:"POST",
            data:{DeptNo:deptPK},  
            dataType:"text",  
            success:function(data)  
            {
                $('#CurrentFiscalData').html(data);
            }
       });  
  });  
 });  

 </script>
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#deptList').change(function(){  
       var deptPK = $(this).val();  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"getdataArea.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{DeptNo:deptPK},  
            dataType:"text",  
            success:function(data)  
            {  
                 $('#areaList').html(data);  
            }  
       });  
  });  
 });  
 </script>
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#deptList').change(function(){  
       var deptPK = $(this).val();  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"getdataShift.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{DeptNo:deptPK},  
            dataType:"text",  
            success:function(data)  
            {  
                 $('#shiftList').html(data);  
            }  
       });  
  });  
 });  
</script>
<table class="CurrentFiscalData" id="CurrentFiscalData">
<tr><th></th><th>Jul</th><th>Aug</th><th>Sep</th><th>Oct</th><th>Nov</th><th>Dec</th><th>Jan</th><th>Feb</th><th>Mar</th><th>Apr</th><th>May</th><th>Jun</th></tr>
<tbody> 

</tbody>
</table>


</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$con = null;
?>
```

I have been searching for a week now, but probably not asking the right question. 
Can anyone please help me with the code or guide me through?